# Unable to install BeautifullSoup in pycharm

Tags: python, package, pycharm

```
DEPRECATION: --no-install, --no-download, --build, and --no-clean are deprecated.  See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/906.
Downloading/unpacking BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
  Downloading BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/BeautifulSoup/setup.py) egg_info for package BeautifulSoup
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/BeautifulSoup/setup.py", line 22
        print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/BeautifulSoup/setup.py", line 22

    print "Unit tests have failed!"

                                  ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...

Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/BeautifulSoup
Storing debug log for failure in /home/jatin/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: how you tried to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because you are trying to install BeautifulSoup in python3, that will only work if you use python2.

In order to install it in python3 use
pip install beautifulsoup4

Comment: Thank You very much
it worked and now i have to study the different functions in this package